# I want emu8086 program which do classify

Tags: assembly

I want an "EMU 8086" program which do classify numbers in string between 0-300
and print the numbers 0-100 on side and 100-200 on another,either 200-300 ??

i do my best and my program doesn't print the values..!

```
org 100h

s1 dw 50,60,70,80,90,100,120,130,140,160,170,190,190,220,250,270,300

MOV SI,0
MOV CX,16

s2:
MOV AX,s1[SI]

s3:
INC SI
CMP AX,100
JBE s4
JA s5

s4:
PRINTf AX
JMP s3

s5:
CMP AX,200
JB s6
JA s7

s6:
PRINTf AX
JMP s3

s7:
PRINTf AX
JMP s3


END
```

Comment: Where's the definition of `PRINTf`?

Comment: What does *either 200-300 ??* mean? Perhaps you could show a brief example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your program for EMU8086 Intel syntax. You just copy-paste and run. This is how it works : DI points to the numbers, depending if number is <100, 100..200, >200, it's necessary to determine if number goes in left, middle or right column, then we do gotoxy (send cursor to screen coordinate), now we have to convert the number to string (because binary looks weird on screen), finally, we display the number. If next number is not zero (zero finishes the process) repeat for next number.

```
.stack 100h
.data

numbers dw 130,50,260,570,180,190,100,20,66,140,860,470,190,20,220,250,170,30,300,0

col1 db 0  ;ROW NUMBER FOR THIS COLUMN.
col2 db 0  ;ROW NUMBER FOR THIS COLUMN.
col3 db 0  ;ROW NUMBER FOR THIS COLUMN.

str  db 6 dup('$') ;STRING TO STORE NUMBER CONVERTED INTO STRING.

.code          
;INITIALIZE DATA SEGMENT.
  mov  ax, @data
  mov  ds, ax

  mov  di, offset numbers  ;DI POINTS TO THE NUMBERS.
while:
;FIND OUT IF NUMBER BELONGS TO LEFT, MIDDLE OR RIGHT COLUMN.
  mov  ax, [ di ]  ;GET CURRENT NUMBER.
  cmp  ax, 100
  jb   left_column  ;IF NUMBER < 100 LEFT_COLUMN.
  cmp  ax, 200
  ja   right_column  ;IF NUMBER > 200 RIGHT_COLUMN.
;IF NO JUMP, THEN NUMBER >= 100 AND NUMBER <= 200.
  mov  dl, 30    ;SCREEN COLUMN.
  mov  dh, col2  ;SCREEN ROW.
  call gotoxy    ;SET CURSOR POSITION.
  inc  col2      ;INCRESE ROW FOR NEXT NUMBER ON THIS COLUMN.
  jmp  continue

left_column:             
  mov  dl, 0     ;SCREEN COLUMN.
  mov  dh, col1  ;SCREEN ROW.
  call gotoxy    ;SET CURSOR POSITION.
  inc  col1      ;INCRESE ROW FOR NEXT NUMBER ON THIS COLUMN.
  jmp  continue

right_column:  
  mov  dl, 60    ;SCREEN COLUMN.
  mov  dh, col3  ;SCREEN ROW.
  call gotoxy    ;SET CURSOR POSITION.
  inc  col3      ;INCRESE ROW FOR NEXT NUMBER ON THIS COLUMN.
  jmp  continue

continue:           
;CONVERT CURRENT NUMBER TO STRING.
  call dollars  ;FILL "STR" WITH '$'. NECESSARY TO DISPLAY IT.
  mov  ax, [ di ]  ;GET CURRENT NUMBER.
  call number2string  ;CONVERT AX TO STRING. RESULT IN "STR".  
;DISPLAY NUMBER CONVERTED.  
  mov  ah, 9
  mov  dx, offset str
  int  21h        
;NEXT NUMBER TO PROCESS.  
  add  di, 2  ;2 BYTES FORWARD BECAUSE NUMBERS ARE "DW".
;CHECK IF PROCESS IS OVER.  
  mov  ax, [ di ]
  cmp  ax, 0
  jne  while  ;IF AX!=0 JMP WHILE.

;FINISH PROGRAM.
  mov  ax, 4c00h
  int  21h           

;------------------------------------------
;MOVES CURSOR TO SCREEN COORDINATES DL,DH (COLUMN,ROW).

proc gotoxy
  mov  ah, 2
  mov  bh, 0
  int  10h
  ret
endp  

;------------------------------------------
;NUMBER TO CONVERT MUST ENTER IN AX.
;ALGORITHM : EXTRACT DIGITS ONE BY ONE, STORE
;THEM IN STACK, THEN EXTRACT THEM IN REVERSE
;ORDER TO CONSTRUCT STRING.

proc number2string
  mov  bx, 10 ;DIGITS ARE EXTRACTED DIVIDING BY 10.
  mov  cx, 0 ;COUNTER FOR EXTRACTED DIGITS.
cycle1:       
  mov  dx, 0 ;NECESSARY TO DIVIDE BY BX.
  div  bx ;DX:AX / 10 = AX:QUOTIENT DX:REMAINDER.
  push dx ;PRESERVE DIGIT EXTRACTED FOR LATER.
  inc  cx ;INCREASE COUNTER FOR EVERY DIGIT EXTRACTED.
  cmp  ax, 0  ;IF NUMBER IS
  jne  cycle1 ;NOT ZERO, LOOP. 
;NOW RETRIEVE PUSHED DIGITS.
  mov  si, offset str
cycle2:  
  pop  dx        
  add  dl, 48 ;CONVERT DIGIT TO CHARACTER.
  mov  [ si ], dl
  inc  si
  loop cycle2  

  ret
endp  

;------------------------------------------
;FILLS VARIABLE STR WITH '$'.
;USED BEFORE CONVERT NUMBERS TO STRING, BECAUSE
;THESE STRINGS WILL BE DISPLAYED.

proc dollars                 
  mov  si, offset str
  mov  cx, 6
six_dollars:      
  mov  al, '$'
  mov  [ si ], al
  inc  si
  loop six_dollars
  ret
endp
```

Let me know if this helped you.

Comment: If you like my answer you can accept it or upvote it (or both !).